# Какое решение можно взять для мультиязычности на сайте?

Tags: php, .htaccess, чпу, mod-rewrite

Чтобы была подмена доменов или же добавления суффикса языка, например:

```
www.site.ru/ru/
www.site.ru/en/

или же www.en.site.ru
```

Как лучше и как это делается правильно?
И как на это реагируют поисковики?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

en.site.ru для поисковика - это домен третьего уровня типа any.narod.ru индексируется как отдельный сайт с учетом языка. Плюс этого способа - возможность для поисковика проиндексировать весь сайт по адресу en.site.ru Правда поисковики стараются выводить вверх домены второго уровня, и лишь потом третьего.

site.ru/en/ для поисковика - раздел сайта. Индексируется как раздел сайта на английском языке. Плюсом получаем возможность выхода повыше в выдаче поисковой системы за счет сохранения домена второго уровня. Минусом - возможность индексации только одного раздела /en/ сайта для английских поисковиков и кракозябры для них в остальных разделах.

Для поисковиков получается лучше первый вариант. На нем они смогут посетить все страницы и не будут ограничены принудительными редиректами. Для размещения повыше в выдаче - второй, но с правильными настройками определения языка, чтобы не отдать иностранному поисковику что-то кроме site.ru/en/

Если что-то не так - поправьте.

Comment: Ответ - супер! Может, кто-то подключится с более технической части к данному вопросу. Вопрос в создании этих поддоменов и как связать я языками на сайте.