# Создание поддоменов для языков

Tags: php

Возвращаюсь к ранее [созданной теме](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/380691/php-%D0%BA%D0%B0%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B5-%D1%80%D0%B5%D1%88%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5-%D0%BC%D0%BE%D0%B6%D0%BD%D0%BE-%D0%B2%D0%B7%D1%8F%D1%82%D1%8C-%D0%B4%D0%BB%D1%8F-%D0%BC%D1%83%D0%BB%D1%8C%D1%82%D0%B8%D1%8F%D0%B7%D1%8B%D1%87%D0%BD%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B8-%D0%BD%D0%B0-%D1%81%D0%B0%D0%B9%D1%82%D0%B5), только с другими вопросами

В проекте имеется один файл с переводами на все языки. Это массив с ключами, обозначающими тот или иной язык.

Когда пользователь меняет язык, номер(ключ) выбранного языка, сохраняется в сессию и от туда вытягивается набор слов для всего сайта.

Сейчас с толкнулся с проблемой определить для каждого языка свой путь, например: www.site.ru/en/  www.site.ru/it   Т- если пользователь переключился на анг.язык. Его путешествие по сайту, везде, будет  `www.site.ru/en/` 
Основная цель - чтобы поисковики съедали сайт на разных языках

К сожалению, идей у меня нет по этому поводу...

Comment: Не надо своего придумывать, уже есть готовое и отлаженное. И работать будет быстрее вашего варианта.

[gettext](https://www.gnu.org/software/gettext/), и подключайте его как хотите. Хоть через site.com/en, хоть через en.site.com

А там можно уже и через htaccess локализацию разруливать

Comment: Я так понимаю это оно: http://php.net/manual/ru/book.gettext.php ?

Comment: Да, я про него. В PHP это не он сам, а клиент к нему (как и stomp, например). Там вроде были некоторые проблемы при смене исходных текстов, но они легко решаются (легко гуглится даже на русских ресурсах)